# How to disable JavaScript in Firefox while running Selenium script?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox

I am using

- Firefox Version: 50
- Gecko driver version: 0.9
- Selenium version: 2.53.1

I tried using below code but it does not work.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
```